# polygon+circle in PostgreSQL Database

Tags: database, postgresql, polygon, geometry

I am trying to use polygon and circle to create a boundaires in my osm mapview in my android app .Is there a way to include both datatype in a single database table.I am now using Postgresql and by defining two tables one for circle and another for polygon.

Comment: Are you using PostGIS, or just the built-in types? What PostgreSQL version?

Comment: i'm trying to post data directly from android to php and then from php to postgreSQL.
my PostgreSQL version=9.1

Comment: You do not want to have a separate table for polygons and circles, a circle is just a type of polygon, after all. Just use POLYGON or Geometry type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want PostGIS.

http://postgis.net/

It has excellent `geometry` and `geography` data types, plus a wide variety of functions for using them. There are lots of useful tools that work with PostGIS for most platforms.